# NodeJS - Error secret required

Tags: node.js, express

i am new to working with nodejs and i'm just trying to start a server that is already working with my teammates.
I am on a mac and already installed all the needed modules with "npm install".
Now there seems to be a problem with the module "cookie-signature", which is already included in the "express"-module. I am trying to start the program and i get no error, but when i try to open the page on localhost:3000, i get the following error:

```
/Users/kevinglaap/Sites/Uni/git/node_server/node_modules/express/node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js:19
  if ('string' != typeof secret) throw new TypeError('secret required');
                                       ^
TypeError: secret required
    at Object.exports.sign (/Users/kevinglaap/Sites/Uni/git/node_server/node_modules/express/node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js:19:40)
    at ServerResponse.end (/Users/kevinglaap/Sites/Uni/git/node_server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:267:34)
    at ServerResponse.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
    at ServerResponse.res.writeHead (/Users/kevinglaap/Sites/Uni/git/node_server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:73:36)
    at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (http.js:932:8)
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (http.js:767:10)
    at res.end (/Users/kevinglaap/Sites/Uni/git/node_server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:282:13)
    at /Users/kevinglaap/Sites/Uni/git/node_server/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session/memory.js:73:11
    at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:244:9)
```

The module is never used in the server resources. I already checked for the usage of the "sign"-function, because the error is a fetched error, which signals that the resources may be doing something wrong, but it is only used by express or other modules within express.
I have been searching the web for days now and haven't found a solution yet. What am i missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you using a module that requires express session to be used? Are you using app.use(express.session(..)) in your server?

Comment: Yes, here's the code:   
var app = express();

app.configure(function() {

[...]
 app.use(express.session({'secret': crypto.randomBytes(64)}));

Comment: I would guess that you have different versions on some of the modules from your teammates. What happens if your teammates update their modules with "npm install" on the project director?

Comment: I can't try that before Tuesday, but i tried changing the usage of the randomBytes-function to a fixed secret word and now everything seems to work, but of course my teammates want it to stay a random secret.

Comment: Did you try logging what returns `crypto.randomBytes(64)` ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When configuring your express instance you need this:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret option here'));
app.use(express.session());
```

Making sure your cookieParser (with your secret String) is before the `express.session()`

Comment: Thank you! This seems to work: app.use(express.cookieParser(''+crypto.randomBytes(64)+''));
app.use(express.session());

Comment: this answer is outdateeeed

Comment: It applies to anyone using express@3.x

Comment: Anyone looking for a solution using express@4.x check out https://github.com/expressjs/session#example

Comment: Not working. 
Error: Most middleware (like session) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately.

Comment: @manking as stated in previous comments. Please see previous comments for Express 4+ solution

Answer (score 4):

with the updated express version:

```
var app = express();
app.use(require('express-session')({ secret: 'keyboard cat', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

**One should add a secret while creating an instance of express-session in middleware.**

Its always a good practice to have .env file for storing all the secrets not just adding a string.

In .env:

```
secret='my_secret'
```

In server.js:

```
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session({
  resave:true,
  saveUninitialized:true,
  secret:process.env.secret,
  cookie:{maxAge:3600000*24}
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    reserve: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie:{secure: false}
})
)
    .env
PORT=6000
CONNECTION_STRING=mongodb://localhost:27017//bookingApp
SECRET=[thinkbeforactingalwas]
MODE_ENV=development
```